# MapboxGL 3D rendering for geometry point

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I was wondering if there is a way for the 3D rendering to work on the circle (from geometry point, not polygon), something like fill-extrude-base, fill-extrude-height for the fill paint type?

Comment: It seems it's mentioned in this post:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-style-spec/issues/456

Comment: A workaround (not a solution) would be to use turf http://turfjs.org/docs/#circle and create a polygon representation of your circle, Turf "Takes a Point and calculates the circle polygon given a radius in degrees, radians, miles, or kilometers; and steps for precision."